# Running agent against a 200K+ documents view (log.nsf)

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript, agent

I have an agent to be manually run against the log file. The documents in the view (Usage/By Date) that I'll be using is more than 200,000. The view is categorized twice. I heard somewhere that you cannot run an agent against a view with more than 200K docs. But I cannot confirm it in my research. Is this true? If ever yes, is there a way I can query in this particular view? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why don't you try it? I don't think there is such a limit. However big operations like that should be run on server side.

Answer (score 0):

There is a list of limits of a Lotus Notes database mentioned in the documentation.  There's nothing about the maximum number of documents you can operate on in an Agent nor any Agent timeout.  I think it'll just take a long time but should work.

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.notes85.help.doc%2Ffram_limits_of_notes_r.html

Answer (score 0):

In 20 years of working with Notes and Domino, I've never heard of a limit like that. However, there are time limits that the Agent Manager imposes on agent runtime.  These are configurable, so you should check with your server admins to determine whether your agent will habve sufficient time to complete the job. Since these limits might change, and the number of documents might increase, it might be prudent to write your code under the assumption that it will need to divide the workload across several runs,